# iis 8 application pool/website creation error windows 10

Tags: iis-8

there was an error while performing this operation

detaions: could not load file or assembly microsoft.web.configuration.apphostfileprovider,version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.enter image description here

Comment: please help with the process to retrive the config file missing.

Comment: Windows 10 does not have IIS 8. Edit your question to include more information please, screen shots and whatever matters. Keep in mind nobody can see your screen over the internet.

Comment: sorry my bad. the version is IIS 10 and the issue got resolved after gacing the dll in VS command prompt.

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as an answer and accept it.